# Not running exe file of window application on anther pc

Tags: c#

I have developed a Windows application on my pc that is x86. When I run the exe of project on anther PC that is x64, the exe file is not executed. What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: "Not executed" sounds like "not working", which is same helpless. I'd suggest to localize the problem first. When you are able to answer on the question "**what** is not working", then maybe someone here can help you to make that working.

Comment: Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

1) Try to set the platform to "Any CPU"

2) Compile a seperate EXE for x64

Comment: This is not necessary a solution. Windows XP/7 x64 are able to run x86 application. If it doesn't work, then problem is not CPU, but some of components used (to example, registry access, you can't use `Registry.LocalMachine`, but should use `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)`). And recompiling will not make a miracle, but could cause other problems instead.